# How to calculate modulus?

Tags: c++, math, modulus

I have a task to create a mathematical formula in c++,  input some variables and get a result.

The problem is that I don't know how to represent and calculate the following:

**sin(3 mod 180)**

I`m aware that mod operator finds the remainder of a division. I can figure that out for 180 mod 3, but for 3 mod 180.

Comment: 3 mod 180 is 3... pheww...

Comment: 3 mod 180 is 3. In C++ you can do this with `3%180`.

Comment: `std::sin(3.0f % 180.0f)`?

Comment: why would you think that `180 mod 3` is a different operation than `3 mod 180`?

Comment: @Proxy: `%` is an invalid operator for `float`.

Comment: For x mod y on floats, try y - int(x / y) * y .  The result for y <= 0 or x < 0 are not well defined.

Comment: @Jarod42 Learn something every day...  Suppose it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers.
When I calculate it with std::sin as Jared42 suggested i get something like 0.14....
and some of you answered that 3 mod 180 is 3...how do you calculate it to get 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ and standard C library provides methods for most arithmetic operations `std::sin` being one of them. You can do mod using modulo operator.

I.e. `std::sin(3 % 180)`